# Best practice project layout with multiple libraries in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have several projects which share some locally developed libraries; these libraries vary from being fairly static to being flexibly updated as the applications that use them grow.

For debugging/update purposes it is useful to have them as part of my project (when a new library version is released I can test/update the library as necessary if bugs are uncovered while running the main application projects).

For building purposes it's a pain that when rebuilding a project it also rebuilds the (sometimes large) libraries.

From my perspective, it would be ideal if some of the libraries could be set to not rebuild or clean unless it is explicitly done. Or if I could switch them between being JAR/AAR libraries vs. full modules.

At this point I wonder if there is a better way.

So, if you want to include a library (for edit/update purposes) in a project but do not want it rebuilding all the time, is there a way and what is the best practice?

FWIW, the basic structure I currently have is:

MainApp

- platform specific code
- Library for app (usually the platform independant code specific to the app)
- Local Utils lib (can be fairly dynamic, but often goes for days/weeks without changes)
- Other Local Utils (fairly static, occasionally updated)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the library as a separate project then install it as a local artifact using `maven plugin` in the library. Read more at [Deploying an Artifact to the Local Cache in Gradle](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-artifact-local-cache)

In your project, you need to add mavenLocal() to the repositories in your root build.gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}
```

And add the dependencies to your project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.your.library:x.y.z'
  ...
}
```

But if your project is shared in your local network, you need to use Repository management like [Artifactory by JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Nexus Repository Manager by Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding...Will this mean that I can make changes to the library source files when I need to while running my main project?

I'm just trying to understand if this is just another way of linking a library/jar.

Comment: It working like the way we work with dependency from remote server like maven central. The benefit is, we can change the library code and publish it to maven local cache. Each time we change the library code, we need to republish it our local maven then we just need to resync the main project to use the latest library code.

Comment: Furthermore, if you don't want to use the latest code from the library (something like x.y.z version), you can use the the x.y.y version which previously published.